# How do I parse this JSON API data in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swift

A beginner here.

I'm having some trouble trying to parse this [json url](https://api.bitkub.com/api/market/ticker?sym=THB_BTC) in SwiftUI

Here is what I've tried:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PriceData2: Decodable {
    
    var id: Int
    var last: Double
    var lowestAsk: Double
    var highestBid: Double
    var percentChange: Double
    var baseVolume: Double
    var quoteVolume: Double
    var isFrozen: Int
    var high24hr: Double
    var low24hr: Double
    var change: Double
    var prevClose: Double
    var prevOpen: Double
    
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var priceData2: PriceData2?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            
            
            VStack(){
                Text("\(priceData2?.id ?? 0)")
            }.onAppear (perform: loadData2)
                
            
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        
    }
    
public func loadData2() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.bitkub.com/api/market/ticker?sym=THB_BTC") else {
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            if let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PriceData2.self, from: data){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.priceData2 = decodedData
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }.resume()  
    }   
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the THB_BTC property of the dictionary that I haven't dealt with but I'm not totally sure of.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First thing to do: don't use `try?` use `do/try/catch` and `print(error)` inside `catch`. Right now, by using `try?` you're losing any chance of getting a meaningful error.

Comment: Second: paste your JSON into [app.quicktype.io](app.quicktype.io) and compare the structs that it generates to what you have.

Comment: Finally: the parsing of data isn't a SwiftUI issue -- it's a Swift issue.

Comment: "I think it has something to do with the THB_BTC property of the dictionary that I haven't dealt with" Yes, you are right. Go ahead and deal with it. The JSON data has to be decoded to a `struct PriceData : Decodable  { var THE_BTC: PriceData2 }`

Comment: When you have a thought but not totally sure of, don't hesitate to try it. Trying does not harm.

Comment: Also, I thing you are going to find that you don't have those individual variables, but rather an `[String:Double]` to deal with.

Comment: @Yrb that is not true, it’s just like any other dictionary that you easily can decode into a custom type like OP has tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

What is missing when decoding is a top level type to hold the price data and there are two ways to solve this, either by using a top level struct or by using a dictionary.

Since the top level key, THB_BTC, seems to be the "symbol" argument from the query and thus might change a top level dictionary is the best alternative here

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: PriceData].self, from: data)
    if let priceData = result.values.first {  //or = result["THB_BTC"]
        print(priceData)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Just for completeness, here is the variant with the top level struct

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "THB_BTC"
    }
    let data: PriceData
}

let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
print(result.data)
```